# I would like to fix php array

Tags: php

I would like to fix php array.

Dear my array as the following :

```
$stmyarr=Array ( [0] => [0]=>aaa,[1]=>ddd,[2]=>bbb,[3]=>ccc)
```

I want to remove [0] =>

So result when display is

```
Array ([0]=>aaa,[1]=>ddd,[2]=>bbb,[3]=>ccc)
```

How to do that ?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous because your example is syntactically not correct. Do you have an array in an array or do you have an empty array value you want to remove?

Answer (score 4):

simple, just reassign the array name to `[0]`

```
// after your original $stmyarr
$stmyarr = array(0 => array( 0 => 'aaa', 1 => 'ddd', 2 => 'bbb', 3 => 'ccc'));
$stmyarr = $stmyarr[0];
print_r($stmyarr);
```

result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => aaa
    [1] => ddd
    [2] => bbb
    [3] => ccc
)
```

Comment: but it display only [0]=>aaa,[1]=>ddd,[2]=>bbb,[3]=>ccc but i need Array ([0]=>aaa,[1]=>ddd,[2]=>bbb,[3]=>ccc)

Comment: but it is array ... let me post

Comment: I fear @JamDvia needs something like `$stmyarr = "Array (" . $stmyarr[0] . ")";`.

Comment: Or maybe `$stmyarr =  print_r($stmyarr[0], true);` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmyarr=array ('0' => array('0'=>'a','1'=>'b','2'=>'c'));
$array = array_values($stmyarr[0]);
print_r($stmyarr);
```

Comment: but it display only [0]=>aaa,[1]=>ddd,[2]=>bbb,[3]=>ccc but i need Array ([0]=>aaa,[1]=>ddd,[2]=>bbb,[3]=>ccc)

Answer (score 0):

it would be just

```
$stmyarr = $stmyarr[0];
```

Reading the array [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) will certainly be helpful in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmyarr=array ( '0' => array('0'=>'aaa','1'=>'ddd','2'=>'bbb','3'=>'ccc'));
$stmyarr=current(array_values($stmyarr));
```